# How to pass information about selected item from DataGrid using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I'm doing my first app using MVVM. I have in "View" declared Datagrid. Code XAML below:

> ```
>             <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="delete">
>                 <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
>                     <DataTemplate>
>                         <Button
>                             Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type> UserControl},Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=DataContext.ClickCommand}">                                 Content="X" />
>                     </DataTemplate>
>                 </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
>             </DataGridTemplateColumn>
>         </DataGrid.Columns>> 
>     </DataGrid>
> ```

In my ViewModel class I can run function that I want after click button "delete" by part of code:

> ```
>     public ICommand ClickCommand => _clickCommand ?? (_clickCommand = new CommandHandler(Delete, _canExecute));
>     public void Delete()
>     {
>      //  DataTable.Rows.RemoveAt();
>     }
> ```

I have problem because I can't get index of selectet row. Source of data in datagrid is dataTable.

Do you have any ideas how to do this?

I've tried something with passing parameter with command of button but I coudn't make it works.

Comment: It's getting even funnier: you can select row 1 while clicking the button in row 2 - so you better not rely on the selected row for a button that exists per row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xmal code

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ViewCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}" Content="X" Background="Chocolate"/>
```

Codebehind code

```
 public RelayCommand DeleteCommand
 {
    get
     {
        return new RelayCommand(p => Delete(p));
     }
 }

public void Delete(string id)
{
 //  DataTable.Rows.RemoveAt();
}
```

This is example you can pass whatever you want in that cmd parameter.

Relay cmd

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> action;
    private Func<bool> canFuncPerform;
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> executeMethod)
    {
        action = executeMethod;
    }
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> executeMethod, Func<bool> canExecuteMethod)
    {
        action = executeMethod;
        canFuncPerform = canExecuteMethod;
    }
    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (canFuncPerform != null)
        {
            return canFuncPerform();
        }

        if (action != null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }


    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (action != null)
        {
            action(parameter);                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I implement also Icommand ID property in my ViewModel right?

Comment: Thanks for your time. I implemented it to my project. I had to change Delete function to        
`public void Delete(object id)
        {
            //  DataTable.Rows.RemoveAt();
        }`

and description of button to:
 `<Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.DeleteCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Content="X" Background="Chocolate"/>`
In fact passing argument works but there is no information about Row that I want to delete, there is only information about all datagrid. Do you have any idea what should I do?

Comment: Id property belongs to row object.   you just verify itemsSource  of dataGrid. Example :- <DataGrid    ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}"/> should be like this.

Comment: Wow it works. Thank you, I need to watch any tutorial or read book to learn MVVM I think. Most things is not so clear for me

Comment: No need of watch any tutorials or books just take one task and implement with different mvvm frameworks. This will help you

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't rely on the selected item. Instead pass the current row item as `CommandParameter`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="delete">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button
                Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl},Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=DataContext.ClickCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                Content="X" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Then of course, use an `ICommand` implementation that is not discarding the command parameter and use it to identify the row to be deleted.

Comment: Can you little help me with that implementation? 
I'm trying something like to indentiy method Delete() but it doesn't work so good.

Comment: @Vades I can't because you didn't provide details about `CommandHandler` and it's not a standard .Net class. Also have a look at raghava answer, it should be pretty close by using the id value as parameter. It all depends on the columns that your viewmodel datatable contains...